# Error while parsing string of time to calendar

Tags: java, type-conversion, datetime-conversion

Im using the following code to convert from string with value **09:10:06**
but in the cal set time I got exception: Unparseable date: "09:19:06"
how can I overcome this issue.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
cal.setTime(df.parse(memberValue));
} catch (ParseException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: If your application is going to be working with dates heavily you might want to consider using JodaTime (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to parse an hour with a wrong pattern.
Here is the fix.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

pattern should be `dd:MM:yyyy`  for `09:10:06` input